# Must Declare Scalar Variable "@Brand"

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, query-builder

The query works fine in SQL Server, however when transferring to Visual Studio Query Builder, I get the error

> Must Declare Scalar Variable

The aim of the query is to display results from the product table initially filtered to a category, then as size, color and brand are selected the results get filtered down.

The function show take in 4 parameters, Category, Brand, Size and Colour

```
SELECT        
    ProdName, SellingPrice, BrandID, Size, Colour
FROM
    ProductTbl
WHERE
    (Category LIKE @category) 
    AND (BrandID = CASE WHEN @Brand IS NULL THEN BrandID ELSE @Brand END) 
    AND (Size = CASE WHEN @Size IS NULL THEN Size ELSE @Size END) 
    AND (Colour = CASE WHEN @Colour IS NULL THEN Colour ELSE @Colour END)
```

Why do i get this error and how can i go about fixing it?

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  The parameters need to be declared and have values.

Comment: In the VS Query Builder it does not allow me use 'Declare'

Comment: Your post is missing what you are asking.  Please state a direct question, like 'why do I get this error?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a stored procedure from your query and call that instead so you dont need to declare those variables. Example call`sproc_get_products 'SomeBrand','SomeColour','SomeCategory','SomeSize'`

Code to create the stored procedure

```
create proc sproc_get_prodcuts (
    @Brand nvarchar(max), 
    @Colour nvarchar(max), 
    @Category nvarchar(max), 
    @Size nvarchar(max) 
)
as
begin
SELECT        
    ProdName, SellingPrice, BrandID, Size, Colour
FROM
    ProductTbl
WHERE
    (Category LIKE @category) 
    AND (BrandID = CASE WHEN @Brand IS NULL THEN BrandID ELSE @Brand END) 
    AND (Size = CASE WHEN @Size IS NULL THEN Size ELSE @Size END) 
    AND (Colour = CASE WHEN @Colour IS NULL THEN Colour ELSE @Colour END)
end
```